# I can login my ssh server without password and private key

Tags: ssh

I disabled root login and password login, changed port, used mosh for a while, but why I can login from a non-root user without password and private key?

Added some info from `ssh -v`, but I did not add option `-i ~/ssh_keys/bandwagon_ssh_key`

```
debug1: Server host key: RSA a4:11:29:3a:7a:...
debug1: Host '[104.224...]:28...' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts:13
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ~/.ssh/github
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ~/ssh_keys/bandwagon_ssh_key
```

Comment: Not enough information to help. Can you login as _any_ user, or just a single user? Does this happen from any remote station, or all remote stations? It _sounds_ like you have a no-password private-public pair set up on two stations, but we don't really know.

Comment: Without password and without private key?

Comment: I support @jdv's suggestion about password-less private key.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Macbook to login to an ubuntu server. The ssh-agent remembers the private keys.

Use `ssh-add -l` to list the keys, use `ssh-add -d ~/ssh_keys/bandwagon_ssh_key` to delete the key.

Actually I move away ~/ssh_keys/bandwagon_ssh_key, so I used `ssh-add -D` to delete all keys.

Answer (score 0):

Because the server already knows your public key and you didn't set a password for the key.
So it just lets you login.
If one was to try this after setting it up as such from a machine that didn't have their keys uploaded it wouldn't let them connect.